# My jCarousel is randomly only scrolling halfway through one of the list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jcarousel

[My jCarousel](http://vanquish.websitewelcome.com/~utopia66/store-display) (on the left) randomly scrolls to the next one, but only *halfway*, leaving all the others out of sync.

Does anyone know how to fix this? It just started happening randomly (though I do get my list items dynamically).

I've tried margins, paddings, heights, etc.

### Update

It seems to happen whenever I add new items to the carousel. Basically my callbacks do this

- As soon as element scrolls up top, it is removed
- When near end of current set, AJAX in a new 5 and append to bottom, then auto click 'next'

### Another Update

Ugh, it still is doing it, even if it takes about 3 minutes to appear. But since this page will hopefully load once, and then remain undisturbed, that will **definitely** be a problem!

Answer (score 0):

check #main-container, setting margin-left around -600px seems to fix the problem